# Can I recover photos and contacts from lost/stolen phone days ago?

Tags: data-recovery, lost-phone

Lost phone (LG Optimus) 2 days ago, anyway to recover photos and contacts?  Reported phone to sheriff's dept and Sprint.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! While waiting for answers, you might wish to start with our [lost-phone tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info) and our [top questions using that tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-phone?sort=frequent).

Comment: Not sure about pics unless it was cloud backed up, but contacts Google back it up automatically in your new phone/ browser log in with same account

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to recover both if your Android phone was synced to your Google account. All you have to do is just sign-in on a new Android phone and all of your data should be redownloaded.

In order to see if your photos were backed up, just go to [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/) and you can view your photos there.